# In Elixir/Phoenix, getting Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/js/hi.js' does not provide an export named 'hiya'

Tags: webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework

In my Elixir/Phoenix app, I added a file called assets/js/hi.js with these contents:

```js
export function hiya() {
    console.log('hiya from hi.js');
}
```

I updated webpack.config.js to include this:

```js
    entry: {
      'app': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js']),
...
      'hi': ['./js/hi.js']
    },
```

In my template, I have this code:

```html
  <script type="module">
    import { hiya } from "/js/hi.js";
...
  </script>
```

When I load the page the following error appears in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/js/hi.js' does not provide an export named 'hiya'
```

How can I get the import to work?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by removing the `'hi'` entry from webpack.config.js, putting `hi.js` into `assets/static/js` and restarting the Phoenix server. This made the `/js/hi.js` path return the literal contents of `hi.js` without any modifications from webpack. Apparently those modifications were causing the problem.